# LaTeX: how to force \uppercase with this setup?

Tags: chapters

**This is what I have:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\setlrmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{1.5cm}{1} 
\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{*}{1} 
\setheadfoot{2\onelineskip}{\footskip}
\checkandfixthelayout
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

%%%%%%
% CHAPTER STYLES
%%%%%%
\makechapterstyle{simple}{
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{1cm}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushleft\chaptitlefont##1}
  }

\makechapterstyle{box}{
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{-58pt}
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{1cm}
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}
%  \renewcommand*{\chapnumfont}{\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{
    \flushleft
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[fill,color=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
      \draw[color=white] (1cm,1cm) node { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }

 % \renewcommand*{\chaptitlefont}{\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries}
 \renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%\flushright\chaptitlefont##1}
 \chaptitlefont\parbox[c]{\textwidth}{\hspace{3cm}##1}}
 }

 \chapterstyle{simple}

%%%%%%
% gør at subsections også nummeres
%%%%%%
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}
\usepackage{parskip}    % Bruges til at lave større mellemrum mellem afsnit
\usepackage{graphicx}   % Required for including pictures
\usepackage{framed}     % Laver boxe 
\usepackage{setspace} % Kan lave forskellige mellemrum mellem linjerne
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}    % Hvis du benytter windows i stedet for linux, så skift utf8 ud med latin1. Tillader danske tegn.
\usepackage{float}      % Allows putting an [H] in \begin{figure} to specify the exact location of the figure
\usepackage{wrapfig}    % Allows in-line images such as the example fish picture

\usepackage[danish]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}                         % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\linespread{1.2} % Line spacing
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}} % Specifies the directory where pictures are stored

%%%%%%
% PAGESTYLE
%%%%%%
\makepagestyle{bachelor}
\makepsmarks{bachelor}{
  \createmark{chapter}      {both}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
  \createmark{section}      {both}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
}
\makeoddhead{bachelor}%
  {}%
  {}%
  {\rightmark}%
\makeevenhead{bachelor}%
  {\leftmark}%
  {}%
  {}

\makeoddfoot{bachelor}{}%
  {\thepage}{}
\makeevenfoot{bachelor}{}%
  {\thepage}{}

\makeheadrule{bachelor}{\textwidth}{\normalrulethickness}

% \setsecheadstyle{\large\bfseries\raggedright}
% \setsubsecheadstyle{\normalsize\bfseries\raggedright}

%%%%%%
% Ændring af indholdsfortegnelsen og litteraturlisten
%%%%%%
\addto\captionsdanish{\renewcommand\contentsname{INDHOLDSFORTEGNELSE}}
\addto\captionsdanish{\renewcommand*{\bibname}{LITTERATURLISTE}}

\nouppercaseheads
\pagestyle{bachelor}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}
\title{Test}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   -1.0 Preface
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\chapter*{Preface}
\lipsum[1-2]


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   -2.0 Table of contents
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}\newpage
\tableofcontents*
\newpage\thispagestyle{empty}\mbox{}
\newpage 

\chapterstyle{box}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   1. Intro
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\chapter{Intro}
\lipsum[1-2]
\subsection{Intro with upper and lower case}
\lipsum[1-1]

\end{document}
```

**Comments:**

Instead of writing 
`\uppercase{\chapter{A chapter}}` I just want to write `\chapter{Intro}`, for it  and make the chapter title in uppercase. I have searched many places, but I haven't found a solution that works.

To make things clear, there are two different chapter styles at work here. One is `\chapterstyle{simple}` and the other is `\chapterstyle{box}`. With `\chapterstyle{box}` it creates a black box with the chapter number inside of it. The box is to the left of the chapter title, and I would like for the chapter title to automatically be with uppercase letters, instead of using the `\uppercase{\chapter{A Chapter}}` each time.

Edit: added some lines to the top, that is important for the alignment of the chapter name, compared the the black box.

**Solved:**
I inserted edit 2 from the chosen answer, from user "cfr". I do use hyperref, so it didn't work at first, but he suggested that *if* I used hyperref, I should use the code from page 158 in the memoir guide and now in works perfect! <3

Comment: Note that you can format code by indenting by 4 spaces. Or highlight and hit the `{}` button in the editor. It would be helpful if you would complete your code to produce a small, compilable document (Minimum Working Example) which people can use to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you want the chapter name in uppercase, too, or just the title so I've changed both:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}

\makeatletter
 \renewcommand\printchaptername{%
   \raggedright\chapnamefont\MakeUppercase{\@chapapp}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushleft\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{#1}}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{A chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image: all caps]

## EDIT

If you want to uppercase the chapter with the `box` style you've defined, you might try something like this. For information on producing a Minimum Working Example, see [these instructions](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\makechapterstyle{box}{%
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{-58pt}%
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{20mm}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \flushleft
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
      \node [text=white] at (1cm,1cm) { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\textwidth-20mm}
        \hspace*{30mm}\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{##1}\par
    \end{minipage}}%
  }

\chapterstyle{box}

\begin{document}

  \chapter{A chapter}

  Some text. What happens to the text?

\end{document}
```

[image: boxed number with uppercased title]

## EDIT 2

To capitalise the ToC entry, you might try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oldfontcommands]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\makechapterstyle{box}{%
  \setlength{\midchapskip}{-58pt}%
  \setlength{\afterchapskip}{20mm}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchaptername}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\printchapternum}{%
    \flushleft
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw [fill=black] (0,0) rectangle (2cm,2cm);
      \node [text=white] at (1cm,1cm) { \chapnumfont\thechapter };
    \end{tikzpicture}}%
  \renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{%
        \hspace*{30mm}\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{##1}}}
\makeatletter
  \settocpreprocessor{chapter}{% see page 158 of the manual
    \let\tempf@rtoc\f@rtoc%
    \def\f@rtoc{%
      \MakeTextUppercase{\tempf@rtoc}}%
  }
\makeatother

\chapterstyle{box}

\begin{document}

  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{A chapter}

  Some text. What happens to the text?

\end{document}
```

[image: caps in toc]

Comment: Just the name of the chapter in uppercase. The "chapter itself" is just a black box with the chapter number inside of itself, so it would look like: 
"[1] A CHAPTER"

Comment: @user38934 So you don't need the stuff between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in that case.

Comment: Just inserted ´\renewcommand*{\printchaptertitle}[1]{\flushleft\chaptitlefont\MakeUppercase{#1}}´
but got this compile error:
"Illegal parameter number in definition of \chs@box.
<to be read again>". I inserted your line both within ´\makechapterstyle{box}{...}´ and outside of it, but same error.

Comment: @user38934 Without a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), it is hard to help. You've posted a fragment of your code but it would be much more effective if you posted a small, compilable document showing how you are using the relevant chapter style. That would make it much less likely that people would waste their time and yours suggesting solutions which don't work for you. You probably need `##1` if you are using it within another formatting command.

Comment: I hope there is enough now and maybe not too much? Sorry to have not done it right to start with, but I'm not very experienced with this, so I hope you will be bearing over with me.

Comment: @user38934 See update. Not sure if this is what you want or not. See the links for information on producing an MWE.

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much. Final question though. Is it possible to also make the chapters in uppercase in the ´\tableofcontents´? As it is now they are not forced for all uppercase, but with whatever they are written with. 
(Only the chapters, not the sections under each chapter)

Comment: @user38934 See edit 2. I think this should solve a problem in the toc as well as capitalise the chapter entry. If you use `hyperref`, take the full code from page 158 of `memoir`'s manual.

Comment: If you shift the black box to the right (for example by \hskip3cm) then you can decide that you have a garbage under this box. This gargabe is visible inside the white number 1.

Comment: I recommend to not use the tikz only for one black box, i.e. for one `\hrule`. This is overkilled. You can use `\hrule height2cm depth0cm width2cm \kern-1.3cm\hbox to2cm{\hfil\color{white}\chapnumfont\thechapter\hfil}
\kern1.3cm` instead `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`.

Comment: @wipet I don't think the final version has garbage under the box. Not when I compile it. I agree that `tikz` is overkill here but the OP was already using it and may well be using it for other things. If not, it would probably be best to use LaTeX boxes.

Comment: This is also a really nice showcase of how easily one can customize the `memoir` class!